# rpm spec file skeleton to real spec file

Tags: variables, replace, rpm, rpm-spec

The aim is to have skeleton spec `fun.spec.skel` file which contains placeholders for `Version`, `Release` and that kind of things.

For the sake of simplicity I try to make a build target which updates those variables such that I transform the `fun.spec.skel` to `fun.spec` which I can then commit in my github repo. This is done such that `rpmbuild -ta fun.tar` does work nicely and no manual modifications of fun.spec.skel are required (people tend to forget to bump the version in the spec file, but not in the buildsystem).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the implied question is "How would I do this?", the common answer is to put placeholders in the file like `@@VERSION@@` and then `sed` the file, or get more complicated and have autotools do it.

Comment: There is just one issue: I personally hate autotools. My favorite buildsystem I use is `waf`

Comment: I'm not a fan either, but which is why I said I would use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

We place a version.mk file in our project directories which define environment variables.  Sample content includes:

```
RELPKG=foopackage
RELFULLVERS=1.0.0
```

As part of a script which builds the RPM, we can source this file:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $(pwd)/Version.mk
export RELPKG RELFULLVERS

if [ -z "${RELPKG}" ]; then exit 1; fi
if [ -z "${RELFULLVERS}" ]; then exit 1; fi
```

This leaves us a couple of options to access the values which were set:

- We can define macros on the rpmbuild command line:

  % rpmbuild -ba --define "relpkg ${RELPKG}" --define "relfullvers ${RELFULLVERS}" foopackage.spec
- We can access the environment variables using %{getenv:...} in the spec file itself (though this can be harder to deal with errors...):

  %define relpkg %{getenv:RELPKG}
  %define relfullvers %{getenv:RELFULLVERS}

From here, you simply use the macros in your spec file:

```
Name:  %{relpkg}
Version: %{relfullvers}
```

We have similar values (provided by environment variables enabled through Jenkins) which provide the build number which plugs into the "Release" tag.

Comment: The aim was to get a spec file that is not dependent upon any scripts, such that I could copy it into `~/rpmbuild/SPECS` and building the rpmspec without any further considerations.
Thanks for your insights though

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

a) use something like

```
Version: %(./waf version)
```

where `version` is a *custom* `waf` target

```
def version_fun(ctx):
    print(VERSION)


class version(Context):
    """Printout the version and only the version"""
    cmd = 'version'
    fun = 'version_fun'
```

this checks the version at rpm build time

---

b) create a target that modifies the specfile itself

```
from waflib.Context import Context
import re
def bumprpmver_fun(ctx):

    spec = ctx.path.find_node('oregano.spec')
    data = None
    with open(spec.abspath()) as f:
        data = f.read()

    if data:
        data = (re.sub(r'^(\s*Version\s*:\s*)[\w.]+\s*', r'\1 {0}\n'.format(VERSION), data, flags=re.MULTILINE))

        with open(spec.abspath(),'w') as f:
            f.write(data)
    else:
        logs.warn("Didn't find that spec file: '{0}'".format(spec.abspath()))


class bumprpmver(Context):
    """Bump version"""
    cmd = 'bumprpmver'
    fun = 'bumprpmver_fun'
```

The latter is used in my pet project [oregano @ github](https://github.com/drahnr/oregano)